# соединить виртуалку с интернетом

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Раздаю интернет на хост машину, хочу, чтобы через нее выходила в интернет виртуалка Ubuntu (на VMware). С CentOS удалось прописать его адрес в "Настройки виртуальной сети" VMware, и всё получилось. Как теперь сделать так, чтобы и Ubuntu могла выходить в интернет? Настройки Ubuntu:
[image: настройки Ubuntu]

/etc/network/interfaces (gateway пробовал и 5000, и 192.168.11.0, и 192.168.11.1)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки вирт сети:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]